# Send an email based on cell name

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send an automatic email when a specific cell name is added in Column G For example when you type the name of an (order) in any cell of the G - column cells it is sent Email automatically from the outlook.

This is the code used

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
    Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
    Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

    Email_Subject = " "
    Email_Send_From = ""
    Email_Send_To = ""
    Email_Cc = ""
    Email_Bcc = ""
    Email_Body = ""

    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
    With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .CC = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        .send
    End With

   debugs:
   If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Check out Ron de Bruin site's as a starting point for VBA mailings https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Comment: I have this code and it works well, but I want to add it only when the name of the cell is entered in column G that sends the email directly

Comment: If cell G1 is not blank the « do send »...

Comment: @CindyMeister That's fine, and thanks for confirming what I thought for the OP. Have a good day or eve depending where you are! Just checked your profile ... Same country! How's the snow? :)

Comment: Check out the workisheet_change event

Comment: [Worksheet_change event](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Worksheet%20Events) ...The code will kick in when you change a cell

Comment: @Davesexcel  :Thank you my friend for your interest
But excuse me where to write the used
Is the code you are using is complete?
It has something that has not been completed

Comment: @SolarMike Just *cold*, here in the "far north" :-)

Comment: @Davesexcel Thank you for your interest in my dear friend, what I did was very well but there is a slight problem. I want to send email only when it is written in the cells of the G or waiting I don't want to send an email when you write any word I just when you write these two sentences just send e-mail.  The other problem is I don't want to show the window to send the email I want to send atomtik want everything within the emails code CC and the sender. I hope you can help me and thank you very much my friend.

Comment: @Davesexcel Comment has been placed in your reply

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your existing code is already good, then you should:

- Go on the top-left of your IDE to the Project Tree
- Click on the sheet you wish to monitor

... and write in there your original code (fixed so that it can take parameters instead of having hardcoded values for email address, subject etc.):

```
Private Sub sendEmail(ByVal Email_Subject As String, ByVal Email_Send_From As String, _
                      ByVal Email_Send_To As String, ByVal Email_Cc As String, _
                      ByVal Email_Body As String)

    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
    With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .CC = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        .send
    End With

debugs:
   If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

... and a listener to the event `Worksheet_Change`, where everytime the modified cell is in the column `G`, the `Sub sendEmail` is called (in this example, I'm passing in parameters the `Offset(0` (same row) `, -n)` (where `n` is how many column before or after `G` the information such as `Email_address` lies):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Split(Target.Address, "$")(1) = "G" And Target.Value = "magic words" Then
        sendEmail Target.Offset(0, -1), Target.Offset(0, -2), ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Just for reference, for example, when I say `Target.Offset(0,-2)`, if `Target` is (let's say) the `Range("G4")`, then `Target.Offset(0,-2)` will be the `Range("E4")` (same line `0`, two columns before `-2`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your cooperation with me
But my problem now is I just want to send email when typing a name done or waiting in this case just send the email
Waiting for the solution
Thanks

Comment: @mego4m just add a condition to your If, like And `Target.Value = "magic words"`. See edit to the answer.

Comment: 'sendEmail Target.Offset(0, -1), Target.Offset(0, -2), ...
'
This code when I type it appears in red as a problem

Comment: @mego4m you can't just copy-paste the code, you'll need to adapt it to your needs. Here I just provided you with an example, the macro `sendEmail` takes 5 parameters and in my example I'm passing just 2 of them to show you how to do it, that doesn't mean the code doesn't need adaption on your real code.

Comment: @mego4m I'm sorry but this is not how the site works. We're not here to work for you, but to help you with specific issues. I've given you enough material to go yourself and make your modifications ;)

Comment: Matteo NNZ@ I know that of course
You are helping
I apologize very much
Thank you very much for your cooperation

Comment: @mego4m no worries, if one of the two answers you had in this post helped you to solve your issue, please accept it so that the thread get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are not labeled fully, each string needs to be dimmed as a string.

For this example email addresses are in column E. great minds @Matteo NNZ?

Just a couple af lines added to the top of your code and placed in the worksheet change event.

copy and paste the code in the worksheet module.

[image]

### Change a cell in column G and the code will produce the email and use the email address in column E.

-
[image]

Complete code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 7 Then Exit Sub

    Dim Email_Subject As String
    Dim Email_Send_To As String, Email_Cc, Email_Bcc As String
    Dim mail_Body As String, Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

    Email_Subject = Target
    Email_Send_To = Target.Offset(, -2)
    Email_Cc = ""
    Email_Bcc = ""
    Email_Body = ""

    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
    With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .CC = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        '.send
        .display
    End With

debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: If you notice in the code I have commented out .send.  During testing, you don't want to be sending constantly. Uncomment when you have the code working the way you want.

Comment: The code gives an example of what to do. There is no way I would know how your actually have you setup if you don't tell us.